# vim is not storing coffeescript file in a buffer

Tags: vim, coffeescript, buffer

My vim is not storing current **coffeescript** file in a buffer. So I can't do **:bp, :bn** or  even **:ls** for **coffeescript** file.

I added this line to my *.vimrc* **:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.coffee setfiletype coffee**, so syntax is recognized.
I am using this plugin: https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script

What can cause this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: is the buffer unlisted? (Do a `:ls!` to show all buffers)

Comment: There is coffee file listed with :ls! command

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with your coffee `ftplugin`; you could try setting an incorrect filetype in your autocmd, such as `setfiletype abcdcoffee`, and check if the problem disapear.

Comment: Do you see the content of the script on your screen? If so there must be a related buffer since a window is just a viewport on a buffer.

Comment: hi mMontu, your solution is working for now - I changed .coffee to abccoffee  - so there is coffee buffer listed now. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a proper solution. Try to find out who's causing this via `:verbose setlocal buflisted?`